# Dealing with exponential operators

Tags: taylor-expansion, vector-analysis, matrix-exponential

I have some troubles with the following equations. First, we define a function $g\left(\hat{\vec{x}}\right) = \exp[-(\vec{x}-\hat{\vec{x}})^2]$. We want to expand $g$ around $\hat{\vec{x}}\approx0$.

My first question is: What does it mean to expand an **operator** around zero? For a real number, I can imagine a small displacement perfectly well, but struggle to do so for an operator.

Next, the expansion is given to first order by
$$g\left(\hat{\vec{x}}\right) \approx g(0) + \nabla g\left(\hat{\vec{x}}\right)|_{\hat{\vec{x}} = 0} *\hat{\vec{x}}$$

My next question is: How do I calculate this gradient? Of course, I first do exponential and square derivative, but how do I then evaluate $$\nabla(\vec{x}-\hat{\vec{x}})$$Shouldn't this then be a tensor? For example, we study stuff like this when looking at a Jacobian. However, in the paper that I am studying, the result is given as a dot product, so the result should indeed be a vector.

Comment: Is $\hat{\vec{x}}$ the position operator?

Comment: To get a good answer, you should probably mention what paper you are reading.

Comment: @Filippo Yes, $\hat{\vec{x}}$ is the position operator. The paper that I am studying is [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.07927.pdf) - Equation (6).

Comment: If I was you, I would add this information to your question; Anyways, after a quick Look it seems like $g$ is the multiplication operator associated to some function $G$. Since the wavefunction has "negligible" density outside some "small" ball around the origin, it would make sense to Taylor-expand $G$ and consider the multiplication operator associated to the approximating function to compute e.g. expactation values. But again, this is Just after having a Brief Look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm going to simplify the notation to save myself typing in latex. I replace the notation $\vec{x}$ for simply $x$ and $\hat{\vec{x}}$ for simply $y$.

Our functional (operator) $g: \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined by
$$
g(y) = \exp\left[-\left(x - y\right)^2\right]
$$

such that if we computed $g(0)$ we would get the **function** $f(x) = \exp\left[-x^2\right]$.

#### What does it mean to expand an operator around zero?

We want to approximate the functional $g(y)$ for $y \in \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ by finding some (hopefully simpler) functional $h: \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ and computing $h(y)$.

Now $h$ will be a bad choice if the difference

$$
\lVert g(y) - h(y) \rVert
$$

is not small.

#### How do i compute this gradient?

Let's assume:

- a) The gradient (now called a Ferchét derivative) exists
- b) That it is in fact
  $$ \nabla g(y) = h(y) = \exp\left[ -(x - y)^2 \right] \cdot 2 (x - y)$$

While we must produce this "qualified guess" of the estimate by sheer magic, we can check whether it is the [Frechét derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) by asserting that
$$
\lim_{\lVert \eta \rVert \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left \lVert g(y + \eta) - g(y) - h(\eta)\right \rVert}{\left \lVert \eta \right \rVert} = 0
$$

Here arises the first problem. While we know that $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space, we cannot compute the limit without knowing the norm $ \lVert \cdot \rVert $. This should be defined in the problem.

For some simplicity, we will choose the L2 norm,

$$
\lVert y \rVert_2^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y(x)^2 dx
$$

Now we can compute the limit
$$
\lim_{\lVert \eta \rVert \rightarrow 0} \frac{\left \lVert g(y + \eta) - g(y) - h(\eta)\right \rVert}{\left \lVert \eta \right \rVert} 
$$
$$\lim_{\lVert \eta \rVert \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \left(g(y + \eta) -g(y) - h(\eta) \right)^2 dx}}{\sqrt{\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \eta^2 dx}}
$$

If we can show that the limit is zero, we have found our Frechét derivative.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. However, I don't think that here g maps from the reals to the space of functions, but from the space of operators to the space of functions? Can I really just replace my vector by a number and proceed?

Comment: I assumed it from the notation:  
 We want to expand $g$ around $\hat{\vec{x}} \approx 0$  
If $\hat{\vec{x}}$ is not in the reals then the phrase  
> What does it mean to expand an operator around zero?  
is impossible to answer because we do not know the norm $\lVert x \rVert$.

Comment: Is $x-y$ an operator?

Comment: Yes. The mapping  

$$\ell(y) = x - y$$

where $y \in \mathbb{R}$ is a linear mapping from the reals to the space of functions

Comment: @Mikal Is$$x-y\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$$defined by $$(x-y)(z)=z-y$$?

Comment: This feels like a misuse of notation. Also could you just explain your point @Filippo ?

Comment: @Mikal $x-y$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, isn't it?

Comment: What I meant is that the linear map $$\ell: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{F}(\mathbb{R})$$ 
defined by 
$$
\ell(y) = x -y 
$$
is an operator / functional from the reals to the space of functions defined on the reals.

Comment: @Mikal Yes, so $\ell(y)$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, isn't it? Is $\ell(y)$ defined by $$\forall x\in\mathbb R:\ell(y)(x)=x-y$$?

Comment: Ahh. Yes ,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: But then $\ell$ is Not linear, is it?

Comment: I see your point, $\ell$ is not linear but rather affine.

Comment: Are you sure your interpretation is correct? Usually $\hat{\vec{x}}$ denotes the position operator, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mikal Thanks for the answer. Why does g map from $F(R)$ in your case? Isn't F(R) an operator and thus takes a vector and not a real number as input?

Comment: @Mikal Now I get it. The point is to just use functional derivatives, not gradients. I didn't see even though it is obvious. Thanks